# Div with nested divs sized really flexibly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

I'm looking for an easy and elegant solution to do the following:

[image]

I've seen a bunch of Q&A here on StackOverflow, however the majority describes some fixed (known) sizes in pixels. What I would like to achieve is really flexible layout where:

1) Position the div at certain vertical position and have it a certain height -> solved with setting `position: fixed; top: 30%; height: 40%;`

2) Position the div at the center horizontally -< tried `width: auto; margin: 0 auto;` but this didn't work

3) Size the nested divs (I'm using the spans right now, but probably that doesn't matter in this context) with their height equal to their width and height of 1 line to be equal to 1/3 (roughly) of the parent div. Also I would like those nested divs to be content agnostic, i.e. set the font size based on the size of the div rather than pushing the divs by increasing the text size. Also, so far the whole thing will break if I exclude couple of captions from the nested divs

So far it looks like this:

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is achievable without any js and I'd be happy to get any advice on this.

Thanks

Update 1: I'm updating the post with the link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfe18mce/), thanks to Sari for the advice.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle so we can help?  Or provide us with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using a [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) for this layout. By its nature a flexbox is a *flexible box*.

Try this:

**HTML** (no changes to [your fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kfe18mce/))

```
<div id="flexdiv">
    <div id="li1" class="li">
        <span id="l1" class="l">1</span>
        <span id="l2" class="l">2</span>
        <span id="l3" class="l">3</span>
        <span id="l4" class="l">4</span>
    </div>
    <div id="li2" class="li">
        <span id="l5" class="l">5</span>
        <span id="l6" class="l">6</span>
        <span id="l7" class="l">7</span>
        <span id="l8" class="l">8</span>
    </div>
    <div id="li3" class="li">
        <span id="l9" class="l">9</span>
        <span id="l10" class="l">A</span>
        <span id="l11" class="l">B</span>
        <span id="l12" class="l">C</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; } 

body {
    display: flex; /* establish flex container */
    justify-content: center; /* center #flexdiv horizontally */
    align-items: center; /* center #flexdiv vertically */
}

#flexdiv {
    display: flex; /* establish (nested) flex container */
    flex-direction: column; /* align li boxes vertically */
    height: 48vmin; /* height relative to viewport size */
}

.li {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    height: 16vmin; /* height relative to viewport size */
}

.l {
    width: 16vmin; /* boxes maintain aspect ratio */
    line-height: 16vmin; /* vertically center text */
    font-size: 7vmin; /* font size scales */
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6bsoze4z/4/

Comment: Thanks for your comment Michael. I really thought I might need to consider a flexbox model but was not sure that it would make a thing working. As for your solution, I have couple of concerns: 1) The spans don't have their heights equal to widths which was one of the requirements 2) The spans in a bottom row are sized differently which should not happen (I didn't state this explicitly in my initial post, however it seems to be obvious from the requirements and the sketch)

Comment: What size do you want the spans to be? Are they supposed to be flexible also, or fixed lengths? Here are the spans, all the same size: http://jsfiddle.net/6bsoze4z/1/

Comment: Michael, those should be flexible and equal to 1/3 of the centered div height, their width should be the same as their height.

Comment: I've revised my answer with a couple more demos.

Comment: Hi Michael, /2 seems not to be working as required as it doesn't preserve the square size of the spans, while /3 from the first glance seems to be the perfect solution. I'll do some further testing and accept your answer as a solution if I don't discover any flaws (though we may need to edit your initial response in order for other people to see the correct answer right there but not in the adjacent comments). Thanks!

Comment: @YaT, I've removed the code and demos that you said weren't working. I've revised my answer to focus on the possible "perfect solution". I understand you're still testing so let me know the results :-)

Comment: Hi Michael, this works like a charm. Thanks once again for your effort, I have now marked your response as a correct answer (I assume checking the tick next to the answer is intended for that purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting top using the calc function:

```
top: calc(30%);
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for posting this. You probably refer to the first sub-question which I successfully resolved by myself, although probably not in a best manner. My main challenge right now is to size the spans properly to have certain height and to have the same width. My understanding is that calc function will not calculate the value from a different property (e.g. calculate width from height) but thanks again for posting this useful approach.

Comment: using variables in SASS you could pass the calc function a value based on the width of the container

Comment: Thanks again Alan. My understanding is that to pass something to the SASS variable I should first know the exact value of it. While in my example I'm trying to get rid of any fixed sizes and operate mainly with percentages (relative sizes). Also as far as I understand SASS is some sort of complication for creating a single page. Please let me know if I'm wrong in any of my assumptions.